# How to close application from terminal same way as exiting it properly

Tags: command-line

Usually when running application in graphical environment, when I want to close it I click `X` in the top left corner of the window or go to `File > Close`.

I would like to sometimes close these programs remotely over ssh from terminal using command line, now I use `kill` command but I wonder it it does the same as exiting the application properly from itself.

From `man kill` default signal appears to be 15) SIGTERM, is this signal going to tell the application I am trying to close to clean up, close open files, save stuff?

Is there a better way if I want to do it from terminal?

Comment: Thanks for asking! I learned something that will surely come in handy at some point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The typical way to close application gracefully is to use `kill -TERM 1234` , where `1234` is the PID of the window. Problem, however, is that graphical applications are designed to listen for a specific signal from X server itself , not listening for the `TERM` signal.

That means you would need some kind of agent in between you and the X server to communicate that you want to send appropriate signal. You can of course write a C program, however there aready exists `wmctrl` program ( not-surprisingly written in C ) that does exactly that.

Usage of `wmctrl` is simple:

```
wmctrl -c :SELECT: # close window that will be selected with pointer
wmctrl -c :ACTIVE: # close currently active window
wmctrl -ic <numeric id> # close window with specific id in hex
```

It's not installed by default, so get it with `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`

There's many uses for `wmctrl` is far beyond just closing windows, so please see more of my answers and Jacob Vlijm's for examples of scripts where it's been used

Comment: Just adding on here that `wmctrl -l` will list all the windows and give the numeric id in hex in the first column.  =)

Comment: Thank you, works great with most of the applications, but with Deluge there is  an option `Minimize to tray on close` and `wmctrl -c` will just close a window, not the application itself, it will stay running minimized to tray.

Comment: Bound this to chrome, closes entire application. Looking for tab closure, like ctrl + w.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's worth adding that `wmctrl -xl` will output results like this:

```
0x03000001 -1 google-chrome.google-chrome  dcentore-pc Rybak - Google Play Music - Google Chrome
0x04600006  0 speedcrunch.Speedcrunch  dcentore-pc SpeedCrunch
```

Where the `x` requests the window *class* to be in the output. This is often the easiest way to close the same program every time. Then, we can just supply the window class when closing it:

```
wmctrl -xc speedcrunch.Speedcrunch
```

This example will close speedcrunch.